# Default option value through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

When I click on a text box field, I call a JavaScript function which will default the option value in a select (`fatcaSearchDO.bankId`).

This is not working when I call `javaCall()`. The value `Option3` is not being set:

```
<html:select styleClass="login-textbox" name="FatcaSearchForm"
    property="fatcaSearchDO.bankId" onclick="checkRadio('2')"
    onfocus="checkRadio('2')"     styleId="BankID" style="width=250">

<option value="Option1"> Option1</option>
<option value="Option2"> Option2</option>
<option value="Option3"> Option3</option>       
</html:select>

<html:text name="FatcaSearchForm" styleClass="login-textbox"
    property="fatcaSearchDO.taxFormId"  maxlength="10"
    onclick=" javaCall ()" onfocus ="checkRadio('3')" />

function javaCall(){
  var bankID=document.all("fatcaSearchDO.bankId");
  bankID.value=' Option3';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `document.all` returns a [*HTMLCollection*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection) of every [*HTMLElement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLElement) on the page; it is a getter, not a method or function so you can't invoke it with `()` or pass parameters such. Therefore, you aren't setting `bankID`.

Secondly, `' Option3'` is not a *value* of the `<select>`, the possible values are `'Option1'`, `'Option2'`, `'Option3'`.

Therefore, you need to change the way you select your `<select>` and what you're setting it to..

```
var bankID = document.querySelector('select[property="fatcaSearchDO.bankId"]');
bankID.value = 'Option3';
```